# How can I get Segment API ID in Campaign Monitor?

Tags: api, campaign-monitor

I am creating a PHP tools which can auto send email campaign via Campaign Monitor using API. I could easily get the ID of a list but not segment. So, how can I get the ID of a segment?

'ListIDs' => array('ID goes here')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script solved my problem.

```
//List all Segment with its Segment IDs
/*
$apikey = 'YOUR API KEY';
$listid = 'YOUR LIST ID';

$segments_wrap = new CS_REST_Lists($listid, $apikey);
$segments_result = $segments_wrap->get_segments();

if($segments_result->was_successful()) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($segments_result->response as $segment) {
        $segment_details_wrap = new CS_REST_Segments($segment->SegmentID, $apikey);
        $segment_details_result = $segment_details_wrap->get();

        if($segment_details_result->was_successful()) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo $segment_details_result->response->Title;
            echo ": ";
            echo $segment_details_result->response->ActiveSubscribers;
            echo "</li>\n";
            echo $segment_details_result->response->SegmentID;
            echo "</li>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}*/
```